# What is the best way to create a fixed side bar with customized tree type list?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to create the below sidebar. However It seems to not rendering correctly as i have a lot of flicker when expand. I used b-nav instead of sidebar as I have a horizontal nav and sidebar seems to cover over horizontal: here are my codes and picture:

There must be a better and easier way to do this. I have search and didnt see anything that speaks to my issue.

[image]

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div>
        <b-row>
            <b-col>
            </b-col>
            <b-col cols="3" class="bg-light border-left">
               <div>
  <b-nav v-b-toggle.collapse-1 ><h4 class="mb-2">Directory of Employee</h4></b-nav>
  <!-----Payroll Frequency---->
  <b-collapse id="collapse-1" class="mt-1">
             <b-nav v-b-toggle.collapse-1-inner size="sm">
      <b-form-checkbox
      id="checkbox-1"
      v-model="status"
      name="checkbox-1"
      value="accepted"
      unchecked-value="not_accepted"
    >    </b-form-checkbox>
                 Monthly</b-nav>
             <!-----Position---->
            <b-collapse id="collapse-1-inner" class="mt-1 ml-3">
                <b-nav class="ml-6" v-b-toggle.collapse-2-inner size="sm">
      <b-form-checkbox
      id="checkbox-2"
      v-model="status"
      name="checkbox-2"
      value="accepted"
      unchecked-value="not_accepted"
    >    </b-form-checkbox>
                    Position</b-nav>
                         <!-----Employee---->
                    <b-collapse id="collapse-2-inner" class="mt-1 ml-5">
                                              <b-nav>
      <b-form-checkbox
      id="checkbox-7"
      v-model="status"
      name="checkbox-7"
      value="accepted"
      unchecked-value="not_accepted">
      <feather-icon size="1x" icon="UserCheckIcon" />Employee Manager
         </b-form-checkbox>
         </b-nav>
                    </b-collapse>
            </b-collapse>
            <!-----Payroll Frequency2---->
            <b-nav v-b-toggle.collapse-3-inner size="sm">
      <b-form-checkbox
      id="checkbox-3"
      v-model="status"
      name="checkbox-3"
      value="accepted"
      unchecked-value="not_accepted"
    >    </b-form-checkbox>
                Fortnightly</b-nav>
             <!-----Position---->
            <b-collapse id="collapse-3-inner" class="mt-1 ml-3">
                <b-nav class="ml-6" v-b-toggle.collapse-4-inner size="sm">
        <b-form-checkbox
      id="checkbox-4"
      v-model="status"
      name="checkbox-4"
      value="accepted"
      unchecked-value="not_accepted"
    >    </b-form-checkbox>
                    Position</b-nav>
                         <!-----Employee---->
                    <b-collapse id="collapse-4-inner" class="mt-1 ml-5">
                        <b-nav>
      <b-form-checkbox
      id="checkbox-5"
      v-model="status"
      name="checkbox-5"
      value="accepted"
      unchecked-value="not_accepted">
      <feather-icon size="1x" icon="UserCheckIcon" />Employee
         </b-form-checkbox>
         </b-nav>
                                 <b-nav>
      <b-form-checkbox
      id="checkbox-6"
      v-model="status"
      name="checkbox-6"
      value="accepted"
      unchecked-value="not_accepted">
      <feather-icon size="1x" icon="UserCheckIcon" />Employee2
         </b-form-checkbox>
         </b-nav>
                    </b-collapse>
            </b-collapse>
  </b-collapse>
</div>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </div>
</template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a bootstrap module that I can install.

Trying it out now to see if it work greats.

https://github.com/kamil-lip/bootstrap-vue-treeview#readme